# Angular initializing service with asynchronous data

Tags: angular, typescript

I created an interface and two classes, A and B, that implement this interface. Then I also created a factory (which is a service) that will return an object of a class, depending on a result of an asynchronous method. This method returns `Observable<boolean>` type. How can I ensure that I get response from said method before someone wants to create an object of A or B? I have to return a synchronous object, not an Observable.

I don't think APP_INITIALIZER works here because everything described above lays in a library that will be imported into main application and I wouldn't want to leak dependency of this lib into main app.
My factory code:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SomeFactory {

private static isEnabled : boolean = false;

constructor(private otherService: OtherService){}

loadState(){
 this.otherService.isEnabled().subscribe((isEnabled) => {
    SomeFactory.isEnabled = isEnabled
  })
}

  static create(): Interface {
    if(SomeFactory.isEnabled) {
      return new A()
    } else {
      return new B()
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SomeFactory {

private static isEnabled : boolean = false;
public instance;                             // it could be an instance of A or B

constructor(private otherService: OtherService){}

loadState(): Interface{
    this.otherService.isEnabled().subscribe((isEnabled) => {
       SomeFactory.isEnabled = isEnabled;

       // It will make isStopped to true as it is going to be unsubscribed
       this.otherService.isEnable().unsubscribe(); // 

       return SomeFactory.createObject();
  })

}


public static create(): Interface{

 // initially isStopped will be false.
 if(!this.otherService.isEnable().isStopped){  
    return this.loadState();
 }else{
   return SomeFactory.createObject();
 }

}
 
private createdObject(): Interface{
    if(SomeFactory.isEnabled) {
      return new A()
    } else {
      return new B()
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The whole point of  `create()` method is to be available everywhere and for everyone in the app, I can't make it private. This method will be called many times.

Comment: so it is like if observable response is received, you want to return A instance otherwise B instance ?

Comment: I want to return instance of either A or B when someone calls `create()` but only AFTER I have the observable response. Depending on the observable i want to return A or B.

Comment: but is it one time process or whenever you call create method, it will going to make a call to API always ?

Comment: It will be called only one time.

Comment: But also can be called every time, it doesn't matter much.

Comment: It matters. Tell me if it will be called every time. I'm gonna update my answer for once only

Comment: Ok, lets go with only once.

Comment: `isStopped` is an observable property

Comment: and of course you can refactor this code. This is just to give you some idea.

Comment: Sadly `loadState()` method won't compile since return statement is inside subscription block